# how to prove this by using generating functions coefficient?

Tags: polynomials, generating-functions

First I should calculate the generating function of $(1-x)^{-1/2}$
and by using that prove this identity:
$$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2k}{k}\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}=4^n.$$
(see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7QH2.gif)).

Answer (score 2):

Note:
I added an explanation
of how squaring the series
gives the result.

First,
by the generalized binomial theorem,
$(1+x)^a
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{a}{n}x^n
$
where
$\binom{a}{n}
=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (a-k)}{n!}
$.

If you put
$a=-\frac12$,
you get

$\begin{array}\\
\binom{-\frac12}{n}
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (-\frac12-k)}{n!}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (-\frac12)(1+2k)}{n!}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2^n}\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (2k+1)}{n!}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2^n}\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (2k+1)(2k+2)}{n!\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (2k+2)}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2^n}\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{2n} k}{n!2^n\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (k+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2^n}\dfrac{(2n)!}{n!2^nn!}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{4^nn!^2}\\
&=(-1)^n4^{-n}\binom{2n}{n}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
(1-x)^{-1/2}
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{-\frac12}{n}(-x)^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 4^{-n}\binom{2n}{n}(-1)^nx^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 4^{-n}\binom{2n}{n}x^n\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$((1-x)^{-1/2})^2
=(1-x)^{-1}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n
$,
by squaring the power series for
$((1-x)^{-1/2})^2
$,
you get the desired result.

The new stuff:

Here is the squaring:

$\begin{array}\\
((1-x)^{-1/2})^2
&=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 4^{-n}\binom{2n}{n}x^n\right)^2\\
&=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 4^{-n}\binom{2n}{n}x^n\right)\left(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} 4^{-m}\binom{2m}{m}x^m\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} 4^{-n}\binom{2n}{n}x^n 4^{-m}\binom{2m}{m}x^m\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} 4^{-n-m}x^{n+m}\binom{2n}{n}\binom{2m}{m}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n} 4^{-n}x^{n}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n4^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2k}{k}\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$(1-x)^{-1}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n
$,
$1 = 4^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2k}{k}\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}
$
or
$4^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2k}{k}\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}
$.

Note:
As in many of my answers,
nothing here is original.

Comment: but what about the proof of  this ?http://i.stack.imgur.com/j7QH2.gif

Comment: I mean can you give a little more explanation for the second part ?

Comment: @generateee: I added an explanation of how squaring the series gives the result.

Answer (score 1):

We have that (see this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) for the details),
$$(1+x)^{-1/2} = \sum_{k\geq 0} \binom{-1/2}{k}x^k\quad\mbox{and}\quad (1+x)^{-1}=\sum_{k\geq 0} \binom{-1}{k}x^k.$$
Moreover $\binom{-1}{k}=(-1)^k$ and
$$
  \binom{-1/2}{k}  
     = (-1)^k \frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2k-1)}{2^k k!} 
     = \frac{(-1)^k}{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}.
$$
Now by [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity),
$$\begin{align*}
(-1)^n&=[x^{n}](1+x)^{-1}=[x^n]\left((1+x)^{-1/2}\cdot(1+x)^{-1/2}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}\cdot \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{4^{n-k}}\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{4^n}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2k}{k}\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}
\end{align*}$$
which implies $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2k}{k}\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}=4^n.$

Comment: more explanation on the second part please ? how it turned from the the line after "now by vandermonde's identity " to the second one

Comment: @generateee Which equality you do not understand?

Comment: how ( -1) ^n is [x^n] ( 1 + x )^-1 and the how it turns to the line after it

Comment: $ [x^n] ( 1 + x )^{-1}$ means the coefficient of $x^n$ of the g.f. of  $( 1 + x )^{-1}$. It is $(-1)^n$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).
After that $( 1 + x )^{-1}=( 1 + x )^{-1/2}\cdot ( 1 + x )^{-1/2}$, Then by using Vandermonde's identity you compute the coefficient of $x^n$ of the product of the  two g.f.s